# phalcon command shows no error no output in Phalcon devtools

Tags: phalcon, phalcon-webtools, phalcon-devtools

I have installed phalcon extension in xampp php 5.6 and windows 10.
phalcon extention is show in phpinfo and in cli command

```
php -m
```

But when I run any command like following, no output or error is shown.

```
phalcon
phalcon --version
phalcon --help
phalcon version
phalcon help
```

Answer (score 0):

have you set your environment variables in my computer?

Comment: Yes.i have but still no response

Comment: can u try edit your code in phalcon.bat file (inside phalcon devtools folder)
set your PTOOLSPATH value same as your phalcon devtools folder

@echo off
                  
set PTOOLSPATH=C:\phalcon-devtools\
php %PTOOLSPATH%phalcon.php %*

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Phalcon like that in any command line. Phalcon is compiled as a PHP extension. It sits in your RAM once loaded. You could access its functionality through PHP code. However, if you meant the Phalcon devtools, you have to download the devtools file eithere from https://github.com/phalcon/phalcon-devtools or autoload via Composer onto your project.

If you do download it from the link above, register the directory in your Environment PATH variables. It should be ready to use.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I downloaded the same as you suggested. and added the system environment path variable as well. but the problem is I dont get any response in case i am doing every thing okay. but if I change the value of path  in environment variable or in phalcon.bat then I get errors.  what could be wrong. could you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

can u try edit your code in phalcon.bat file (inside phalcon devtools folder) set your PTOOLSPATH value same as your phalcon devtools folder

`@echo off 
set PTOOLSPATH=C:\phalcon-devtools\ 
php %PTOOLSPATH%phalcon.php %*`

Comment: yes I have edited that as well. and if I put a wrong path there , it shows me an error. but when the path is true, I dont get any response and thats the problem here

Comment: are u sure that u are downloading phalcon version as same as the xampp and php version? if u have xampp v86 then u should download phalcon x86 v3.4